# What to call an object that inspires aspirations?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests

Take [this](http://www.flickr.com/photos/cam_95/6979175518/) building. I find it particularly inspires in me aspirations – aspirations of social prestige and material success.

So I am then aspirational. Is there a word that describes the building, with its role of inspiring aspirations in people? "aspirational" almost feels like it fits, but [its definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/aspirational) seems to limit it to the beings who aspire:

> having or characterized by aspirations to achieve social prestige and material success

Is "aspirational" a valid word to describe that building? If not, what words might be appropriate in conveying "the inspiration of aspiration"?

Comment: [A _MacGuffin_.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacGuffin)

Answer (score 1):

**Inspirational**

> adjective 
>   1. providing or showing creative or spiritual inspiration. "the team's inspirational captain"   [Google]

Comment: This was also the first word that came to my mind.

Answer (score 1):

*inspire* and *aspire* share the same latin origin, based on the word *spirae* (to breathe). The prefix *in* (into) is causative. The prefix *a* (from "ad", meaning "to") is effective.

You are looking for the causative (that which causes you to aspire is that which inspires you). The word is **Inspirational** (*in* + *spirae* + *al* where *al* ties the word to mean *act of (verb)ing*, or in this case *act of breathing into* or, in modern interpretation, *act of inspiring*.)